# Need help on Regular expression to extract sql sub query

Tags: regex

i am new to regx...i want to get the subquery from given query using regular expression.

For example i have query like following

```sql
Select * from (
   select * from Table_A where ID = 90 
   UNION 
   select * from Table_B where ID = 90
)  as SUBQUERY left join TABL_ABC abc ON (abc.id = SUBQUERY.id)
```

now i want my regular expression to match following lines only:

```sql
select * from Table_A where ID = 90 
   UNION 
   select * from Table_B where ID = 90
```

Please help me, Thank you in advance...

Comment: How complex will your subquery be?

Comment: @Passerby Your edit modified the question. In the original version it was looking for a regexp in a single line. Now it involves multiple lines, which might make a difference when using regexps.

Comment: @OlafDietsche They **ARE** multiple line statements. OP was using backtick to quote his multiline statements, so they're displaying as single line -- one [Enter] in SO's editor only results a space, and it seems OP wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @Passerby Ok, my fault, I didn't spot this. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a simple subquery without additional braces, you can just use this regexp

```
/\(\s*(select[^)]+)\)/i
```

Comment: Thank you Olaf Dietsche...Its working awesome, could you please help me to get some study material on the same... it will be great...!!!

Thank you very much.... :-)

Comment: @Sid I think any tutorial on regexps will do. When you follow [regexp info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info), at the end are some links. http://www.regular-expressions.info/ comes to mind as well. Just search for "regexp tutorial" or "pcre tutorial".

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$sql = 'Select * from ( select * from Table_A where ID = 90 UNION select * from Table_B where ID = 90 ) as SUBQUERY left join TABL_ABC abc ON (abc.id = SUBQUERY.id)';

if( preg_match('/\(\s*(select.+)\) as /iU', $sql, $matched ) ){
    $subquery = trim( $matched[1] );
    var_dump( $subquery );   
}
```